# iptables cgroup filter not matching

Tags: linux, iptables, cgroups

I need to make sure only specific services can access my vpn's virtual interface. From what I can tell, using iptables to filter based on process cgroup membership is the cleanest way to do that.

So, I put my sshd service in the `vpn.slice` cgroup using systemd, and I made a chain and added it to both INPUT and OUTPUT:

```
iptables -N vpn
iptables -A vpn -m cgroup --path /vpn.slice -j ACCEPT
iptables -A vpn -j DROP

iptables -A INPUT  -i $INTERFACE -j vpn
iptables -A OUTPUT -o $INTERFACE -j vpn
```

iptables -L output:

```
[root@sh ~]# iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 287K packets, 17M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  106  5160 vpn        all  --  homeforward any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 476K packets, 673M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   78 10062 vpn        all  --  any    homeforward  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain vpn (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             cgroup /vpn.slice
  184 15222 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

I can't connect to the ssh server when these rules are applied, and same for netcat on other ports. Manually changing a shell's cgroup membership and trying to ping other nodes in the vpn also doesn't work. I've also tried using `--path vpn.slice` instead of `--path /vpn.slice`, it doesn't make a difference.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can't tell if the cgroup config is the one expected (it wasn't provided), but you have to read this part in `man iptables-extensions` below cgroup: "IMPORTANT:  when  being  used in the INPUT chain"

Comment: Hi. I'm facing the same scenario. were you able to find a solution to this ?

Comment: @Mahe No, unfortunately, what I ended up doing is making a separate VM that acts as a DMZ. It reverse-proxies traffic to the services I wanted to let use the VPN with nginx, so it's not a matter of restricting other processes from accidentally using the VPN, it's just a matter of only forwarding the web requests I wanted to expose services for. That works for what I needed, sorry if that doesn't work for you. I barely ever have luck trying to do shenanigans with iptables.